# I cannot update my Surface Pro 6 to Windows 10 1809

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro, windows-10-v1809

I did both of them.

- Settings -> Update & Security
- Click 'Update now' of https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and execute `Windows10Upgrade9252.exe`

There are several users have the same issue.

- https://twitter.com/GlynPress/status/1067486762593910790
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-6-wont-upgrade-to-windows-10-1809/8bb7c903-cb1c-4391-a8fc-5858caa48651

Is not this update pushed to Surface Pro 6 yet?

Comment: I would really wait until Microsoft decides to push you this version. Much safer.

Comment: That's true. I think this post help people understanding what happens to Surface Pro 6 and Windows 10 1809.

Comment: “Is not this update pushed to Surface Pro 6 yet?” - This entirely depends on the channel you have selected (Semi-Annual Targeted vs Semi-Annual)

Answer (score 0):

Your link is ok

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If Windows10Upgrade9252.exe doesn’t help, you need to analyze the reason for update failure, disable security software, reset update components and run Update Assistant again.

Another method is in-place upgrade, click Download tool now button, use media creation tool to download 1809 iso, mount iso and click setup.exe.

Answer (score -1):

I just upgraded my Surface Pro to Windows 10 build 1809.
Here are the steps I did:

1. Open your web browser and go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and click "**Download tool now**".
2. Double-click on the **MediaCreationTool1809.exe** file you've downloaded.
3. Agree the license terms.
4. Select the "**Upgrade this PC now**" option and click Next.
5. Just wait to complete the upgrade process.